# How do I set the values of my mat-select checkbox from the typescript file in a component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to retain the value of my checkboxes when I return from a previous page. To achieve this, I've saved the objects I want to have checked to a service. 
It seems the form control works in a strange way, rather than using booleans, it appears to store the selected values in an array.

I thought the answer was to retrieve my values from the service, then use the setValue() method on the formcontrol to pass in the values.
However this does not appear to update the checkboxes on the template as expected.

**relevant part of template**

```
  <mat-form-field style="padding-left: 10%">
    <mat-label>Select a Database</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="databases" multiple (ngModelChange)="selectDatabases();">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let database of databaseList" [value]="database">{{database.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="databaseList != null" style="padding-left: 10%">
    <mat-label>Select a collection</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="collections" multiple (ngModelChange)="selectCollections();">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let collection of collectionList" [(value)]="collection">{{collection.name}} <i
          style="color:#808080">{{collection.dbName}}</i></mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**databases and collections are the FormControls I'm trying to manipulate**

```
  // angular form
  public databases = new FormControl();
  public collections = new FormControl();
```

**retrieve the values from the service**

```
if (this.isBack === 'true') {
      this.selectedDatabases = this.pageLoadService.getSelectedDbs();
      this.selectedCollections = 
      this.pageLoadService.getSelectedCollections();
      this.setCheckBox();
    }
  }
```

**attempt to set the checkbox values in my ts file**

```
  setCheckBox() {
    this.databases.setValue(this.selectedDatabases);
    this.collections.setValue(this.selectedCollections);
    console.log(this.selectedCollections);
    console.log(this.collections);
  }
```

I've used console.logs() and can see when I return to the page, it does correctly retrieve the values from the service, and the formcontrol values are being updated to include my array of collections & databases. However, the template does not appear to reflect this, the options don't appear to be selected.

Comment: Did you try to do `this.collections.updateValueAndValidity();` after setting the value?

Comment: Yeah I've just tried that, still no luck

Comment: This can be a reference issue. make sure that `selectedDatabases` and `databaseList` have reference to common objects.

Comment: Maybe the objects are different. Try to set an ID as value of the mat-option instead the whole object.